# plpgsql function which contains the query "Select * from table name"

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to create a plpgsql function that will execute a simple select query,i.e. "Select * from table name" .When i will run that function by this query which is like
"select function()",then it will return the output as "Select * from table name".

Comment: Do you really want the function to return the string value `'Select * from table name'`? Or do you want it to return the _result_ of that query?

Comment: actually i want the result of that query.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a PL/pgSQL function. A simple SQL function will do:

```
create or replace function get_result()
  returns setof table_name
as
$$
  select * from table_name;
$$
language sql;
```

But you need to use `select * from function();` to get the result **not** `select function()` because set returning functions can only be used in the `from` clause.